# How do I establish why compilation of code hangs with mpif90?

Tags: compilation, fortran, mpi, openmpi, intel-fortran

I am trying to compile a parallel TDDFT code written in Fortran (https://octopus-code.org/), but the compilation hangs.

I'm compiling with openmpi (2.0.0), built with the intel compilers (16.0.3 20160415)

And the command make hangs at is:

```
mpif90 -O3 -check bounds -free -I ../external_libs/bpdn -I ../external_libs/dftd3 -I ../external_libs/spglib-1.9.9/src/ -I /home/c/cor22/scratch/bin/src/octopus/../libxc-5.0.0//include -I/usr/include -I/home/c/cor22/scratch/bin/src/octopus/../libvdwxc-0.4.0//include  -c  -o td/td.lo td/td_oct.f90
```

I've never seen a compiler hang like this before, and am wondering if anyone knows what the issue may be, or how to establish what is causing it?

The make process has managed to proceed through a large part of the source, compiling happily enough.

Comment: have you tried compiling it without optimization and debug enabled? hopefully this yields some insight.

Comment: check if memory swap occurs. FWIW, you are using obsolete Open MPI (now is `4.0.5`) and `intel` (now is `2020`).

Comment: Try to isolate the problematic part of the code. Try deleting first half of the module. Does it compile? Try deleting the other par of the module. Does it compile? Intel Fortran Support forums are normally quite responsive and you might even be eligible for the Premier Support, although probably not, because version 16 is quite old. Try to get a more recent compiler.

Comment: Tried without optimization, and debug but same result. Going to use a newer compiler/mpi combo. Was just curious as I have never seen this happen before.